# Best place to install Java se development kit

Tags: java-8

To use netbeans, I downloaded jdk 8 and installed it, in C drive under win 7 Os programs folder. I have also Java 8 update in D drive.
Can I install Java se development kit in D drive too, without side effects?

Thanks ahead
Kian William

Answer (score 1):

I always install JDKs under an x:/tools directory (where x can be any drive letter, by preference not the root drive).

It's quite possible, and works fine. Take care with your JAVA_HOME settings of course, as they need to reflect this location :)

If anything, this works better than installing it under c:/program files/ as some tools have trouble with pathnames that have spaces in them.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the response, in that case I shall uninstall it and reinstall again
from the beginning. 
Kian William